# Hiding soft input keyboard from AlertDialog in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am facing an issue while invoke hide soft keyboard from alert dialog.

My alert dialog contains an edit text with input type of number.

While focusing on edittext, after clicking/touching outside the alert dialog my numeric keyboard hides but my alphabetic keyboard getting showed.
i.e. numeric keyboard switches to alphabetic keyboard, but keyboard doesn't hide completely.

I think this is an issue from softinputkeyboard handling.

Comment: Do you have some listener that gets invoked while touching outside the alert dialog?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for hiding the keyboard inside alert dialog:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(**dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken()**, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); // here view should be dialog window decor token
        }
```